# Visual Studio Blog

Tags: visual-studio

I want to write a blog and some of the blogs that I've seen on the Internet have code snippets in VB.NET or C# that look like the text in Visual Studio itself even with the colors.

Is there some sort of application or tool I can use to create code snippets that look like those other blogs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) is a good one.

Also, [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter) looks great, but I haven't tried it myself.  It has [explicit support for VB.NET](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter:Brushes:VB).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Windows Live Writer for a blog editor I recomend using "Paste from Visual Studio" ([link](http://gallery.live.com/liveItemDetail.aspx?li=d8835a5e-28da-4242-82eb-e1a006b083b9&l=8)).  It's a great way of getting formatted code into your blog posts.

Answer (score 0):

I use [this site](http://www.manoli.net/csharpformat/) to convert my code to HTML-formatted text for my blog. Works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using another application, [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/) exports your files to HTML.

Just open your *.cs files and go to Plugins > NppExport > Export to HTML.  Fonts and colors are preserved, as defined in your Notepad++ configuration.

FYI, Notepad++ exports to HTML 4.01